# Bash command variable assignment

Tags: bash

If I assign a variable:

```sh
testThis='echo "This is a test"'
```

If I use `$testThis`, it works in a script.

But, what if I want to skip a line ?  So I try:

```sh
testThis='echo; echo "This is a test"'
```

and this fails!

Can't figure it out after much effort trying `$()` command substitution and all sorts of quoting.

Comment: Don't use variables to store commands. Use functions. See: [BashFAQ/050: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 2):

A parameter expansion is not reparsed. The following

```
testThis='echo; echo "This is a test"'
$testThis
```

is equivalent to

```
echo ';' echo \"This is a test\"
```

The semicolon and the double quotes are both literal parts off the string, not shell syntax. After word-splitting and quote removal, the shell identifies the command `echo` with six arguments:

1. `;`
2. `echo`
3. `"This`
4. `is`
5. `a`
6. `test"`

Use a function instead:

```
testThis () {
    echo; echo "This is a test"
}

testThis
```